# How many solutions does $C = A \sin \alpha + B \sin(\arccos (a) - \alpha)$ admit, and in what conditions?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How many solutions, and under what conditions this equation admit solutions:

$$C = A \sin \alpha + B \sin(\arccos (a) - \alpha)$$
with A, B, and C are positive real numbers, and $-1\leq a \leq 1$. In btw, I think in some cases we might have two solutions, are the two solutions one acute and the obtuse?

Comment: Please avoid using “$a$” and “$\alpha$” in the same neighborhood; never, please, never, in the same formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma:** There exists a solution $t$ to the equation $C=A\sin t + B\cos t$ iff $C^2 \le A^2+B^2$.

**Proof:** Let $\cos x = \dfrac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}, \sin x = \dfrac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\implies \sin t\cos x+\sin x\cos t=\dfrac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$. Since $C^2\le A^2+B^2 \implies \left|\dfrac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}\right| \le 1$. Thus we can choose an angle $\omega$ such that $\sin \omega = \dfrac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$. Thus: $\sin(t+x)=\sin \omega\implies t+x=\omega+2n\pi\implies t = \omega - x+2n\pi$. We now use this lemma to solve the main question.

**Let** $\theta = \cos^{-1}(a)\implies C = A\sin\alpha + B\sin(\theta - \alpha)= A\sin\alpha+B(\sin\theta\cos\alpha-\sin\alpha\cos\theta)=(A-\cos\theta)\sin\alpha+B\sin\theta\cos\alpha$. By the lemma we proved above: $C^2 \le (A-\cos\theta)^2+(B\sin\theta)^2$, and this turns out to be the condition that we need for the equation to have a solution in $\alpha$.

Comment: It “turns out”? How so? The existence of a solution is not immediately obvious

Comment: I've edited it. Please check out my answer to see if it works.

Comment: Seems good to me, but maybe it’s more rigorous (just in case you somehow introduced an extraneous solution, which I don’t think you did) to replace the implies with “iff.” where possible, else directly show $t$ is a solution